# Revise Excel "Find" formula to find more than one possible end value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trim

I have a formula that is working well for me. It is taking the body of an email and chopping up into fields. This is the formula for the "cost should be" cell.
=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(B463)),FIND("Cost Should Be:",TRIM(CLEAN(B463)))+15,FIND("Retail:",TRIM(CLEAN(B463)))-FIND("Cost Should Be:",TRIM(CLEAN(B463)))-15)

The one problem I have is that sometimes people skip a field that they don't have a value for. In this case there is no "retail" to be found. The next field would start "sales".

Is there a way I can edit this formula to have the end value show an "or" statement? Meaning instead of saying find (retail..) it would say find (retail, or sales, or etc..). So it just finds whichever the next is?

I also have an issue with the results having spaces in from of them. Any way to get rid of the space, without having to manipulate the data after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version for "Retail:" or "Sales:"...with an extra TRIM to get rid of any leading or trailing spaces

`=TRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(B3)),FIND(IF(COUNTIF(B3,"*Retail:*"),"Retail:","Sales:"),TRIM(CLEAN(B3)))-1),1,FIND("Cost Should Be:",TRIM(CLEAN(B3)))+14,""))`